# An elementary question about For loop

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume we have this `For` loop:

`For[i=1,i<10,i++, i^2]`.

How can we put the squared values `i^2` into a list?

Comment: `Table[i^2, {i, 9}]`. `Range[9]^2`. [See this post.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica).

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate but Szabolcs' answer there gives several alternatives along with explanation of why they are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

`For` loops are very ugly in *Mathematica* and should be avoided whenever possible.  @march's solutions are so much more elegant.

But if you're wedded to the idea of using a `For` loop, here's a very ugly approach to your problem:

```
mylist = {};
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, AppendTo[mylist, i^2]]
```

and then

```
mylist
```

Comment: With `For`, an even uglier approach but more efficient than using `AppendTo` is flattening nested lists. `mylist = {};
(For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, mylist = {mylist, i^2}]; 
 mylist = mylist // Flatten;)`

Comment: Gosh... perhaps we should start a contest for the ugliest solutions to problems!